# Using mod_wsgi hosted flask app to emit as an external process to a Flask-SocketIO server running on gunicorn with eventlet worker

Tags: python-3.x, flask, mod-wsgi, flask-socketio

I have a flask app deployed on elastic beanstalk. It's a REST api that mostly does database CRUD operations and not much heavy computation. The default configuration provided is Apache+mod_wsgi which doesn't support Flask-SocketIO. Although I managed to replace it with an nginx+gunicorn+eventlet setup. It is working well but I face some deployment issues with it sometimes.

Using the default mod_wsgi setup and using that to emit data as mentioned here
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#emitting-from-an-external-process and running a flask-socketio server sharing the same Redis message queue, I was able to emit data from the mod_wsgi instance and it seems to be working well.

Can anyone tell me if there could be any issues with Flask-SocketIO with such configuration or is the gunicorn+nginx way suited better? I would shift to it if I face any further issues with current configuration.

Comment: `I face some deployment issues with it sometimes.` Can you expand on these issues?

Comment: I've modified aws deployment scripts using ebextensions to stop apache and start gunicorn and nginx in it's place. But sometimes the gunicorn process doesn't stop or start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no issues, but there are disadvantages.

External processes cannot receive events, and cannot receive callbacks for events they emit. So make sure this isn't going to be a limitation down the road.

Another option that you have is to connect your mod_wsgi server to your Flask-SocketIO server as a Socket.IO client instead of as an external process. If you connect as a client you do not need to use a Redis queue, the connection is done over long-polling and/or WebSocket.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel. That is indeed going to be a limitation. I'll try the client approach then. Unfortunately there don't seem to be any stable and maintained socket.IO client libraries in python. [socketIO-client-2](https://pypi.org/project/socketIO-client-2/) seems to the best from what I've tested. Are you aware of any other?

Comment: I maintain my own client these days. It's in the python-socketio package that you have installed as a dependency of Flask-SocketIO. You may need to upgrade to latest to get the client, but it's there. Check out the docs for help on usage.

Comment: Awesome. I wasn't aware of that. I'll check it out. Thanks a lot!